# How .bat can check if curl or wget exist

Tags: windows, curl, batch-file, wget

In my .bat file, how can I check if wget or curl are available in the system through whatever other previous installations the user may have went through. Is this check possible, and can I have `if then else` logic in my file to react differently, like we do in normal programming. I basically want to use wget or curl to download a file.

```
If (wget is available)
   do something
else if (curl is available)
   do something else
else 
   tell the user they are out of luck
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check whether command is available in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686737/check-whether-command-is-available-in-batch-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the path where you'd expect to find the EXE, it's fairly easy:

```
IF EXIST C:\Windows\wget.exe ( *** do something with it ***)
```

...of course you could do `IF NOT EXIST` with a blurb to copy it, or use an `ELSE` statement.

Otherwise, if you don't know where you might find the file, you can search for it with something like this (original source found [here](http://ss64.com/nt/which.cmd.txt)):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
(set WF=)
(set TARGET=wget.exe)

:: Look for file in the current directory

  for %%a in ("" %PATHEXT:;= %) do (
     if not defined WF if exist "%TARGET%%%~a" set WF=%CD%\%TARGET%%%~a)

:: Look for file in the PATH

  for %%a in ("" %PATHEXT:;= %) do (
     if not defined WF for %%g in ("%TARGET%%%~a") do (
        if exist "%%~$PATH:g" set WF=%%~$PATH:g))

:: Results
  if defined WF (
    *** do something with it here ***
  ) else (
    echo The file: "%~1" was not found
  )
```

You could wrap that whole block into a function and call it once for each EXE (change the `%TARGET%`s back into `%~1`, give it a :TITLE, then `call :TITLE wget.exe`)...

Alternately, you could take a different approach and just try the commands and see if they fail. Since ERRORLEVEL of 0 usually means success, you could do something like this:

```
wget -q <TARGET_URL>
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 (
  curl <TARGET_URL>
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 (
    ECHO Download failed!
    EXIT 1
  )
)
:: now continue on with your script...
```

Comment: Incidentally, the site [http://ss64.com/nt/](http://ss64.com/nt/) is an excellent resource for NT CMD Shell tips & tricks. (And don't miss the [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html) page!)

Comment: Second approach sounds good enough for me. I think the searching will lengthen the execution time of the script unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell v3 CTP1 comes with a command like wget/curl. It's called Invoke-Web-Request. To learn more, you can visit this post: http://rambletech.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/windows-powershell-v3-includes-command-like-wgetcurl/