# Check whether command is available in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I'm writing a batch file for Windows and use the command `7z` (7-Zip). I have put the location of it in the PATH. Is there a relatively easy way to check whether the command is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An attempt to execute `7z.exe` will return an `%errorlevel%` of 9009 if the command is not found.  You can check that.

```sh
7z.exe
if %errorlevel%==9009 echo Command Not Found
```

***Note**: This solution is viable for this specific `7zip` use case, and likely for plenty of others. But as a general rule, executing a command to determine whether it's present could potentially be harmful.  So make sure you understand the effect of executing the command you're checking for, and use your discretion with this approach.*

Comment: A nicer way would be `7z.exe >nul 2>&1 | echo Command not found`, I guess.

Comment: In this case, this works, but this is a risky habit to have -- what if one tried `delete-hard-drive.bat` to test its existence?

Comment: @ErichGubler, I was never suggesting the original poster use this as an across the board solution.  I answered with an option that works-- and is harmless-- for his specific use case. For that reason, I don't think it deserved a downvote.

Comment: @Marc, a disclaimer would be enough for me to remove my downvote! :)

Answer (score 30):

Do ***not*** execute the command to check its availability (i.e., found in the `PATH` environment variable). Use [`where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/where) instead:

```dos
where 7z.exe >nul 2>nul
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 (
    @echo 7z.exe not found in path.
    [do something about it]
)
```

The `>nul` and `2>nul` prevent displaying the result of the `where` command to the user. Executing the program directly has the following issues:

- Not immediately obvious what the program does
- Unintended side effects (change the file system, send emails, etc.)
- Resource intensive, slow startup, blocking I/O, ...

You can also define a routine, which can help users ensure their system meets the requirements:

```dos
rem Ensures that the system has a specific program installed on the PATH.
:check_requirement
set "MISSING_REQUIREMENT=true"
where %1 > NUL 2>&1 && set "MISSING_REQUIREMENT=false"

IF "%MISSING_REQUIREMENT%"=="true" (
  echo Download and install %2 from %3
  set "MISSING_REQUIREMENTS=true"
)

exit /b
```

Then use it such as:

```dos
set "MISSING_REQUIREMENTS=false"

CALL :check_requirement curl cURL https://curl.haxx.se/download.html
CALL :check_requirement svn SlikSVN https://sliksvn.com/download/
CALL :check_requirement jq-win64 jq https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

IF "%MISSING_REQUIREMENTS%"=="true" (
  exit /b
)
```

**PowerShell**:

On `PowerShell`, the `Get-Command` cmdlet can be considered to be the equivalent of cmd's `where.exe`.

```
Get-Command <cmd>
IF ($? -ne $true)
{
    Write-Host "<cmd> not found in path"
    # Do something about it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup:

```sh
@echo off
set found=
set program=7z.exe
for %%i in (%path%) do if exist %%i\%program% set found=%%i
echo "%found%"
```

Comment: Thanks, why do you say `set found=`?

Comment: @Joey there is an easy fix for that. Use double quotes. However, this wont work if the extension of command (exe, bat) is not specified while the accepted solution will.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, open a command window and type "7z" (I assume that is the name of the executable).  If you get an error saying that the command or operation is not recognised then you know the path statement has a problem in it somewhere, otherwise it doesn't.